# Cube Processing SQL Server Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

Is this possible? It seems when I try and do this manually or via an SSIS task it does not work whereas it will be fines with other editions.

(I'm using my local developer edition as a test environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this. I had to configure my analysis services instance to use my account rather than the built in account in SQL Server Configuration manager

Comment: I always use separate accounts for sql services, eliminate random stuff not working.

Answer (score 2):

Fine with other editions on your local workstation?

Developer should be the same as enterprise, they say.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Sql Server Developer edition has the same features as the enterprise edition
What error do you get?
Is the data source of your local cube pointing to the right db?

Comment: I was trying to do it via SSIS, but get an error when connected to the Analysis Servcies instance in management studio and ricght clink on cube/pressing process.

The error is a security error even though I'm logged in